# Add String to New Line After Final Pattern Match

Tags: xml, awk, sed, tags, kml

I am trying to add the follow string *after* the last pattern match in a text file.

**Text File**

```
<MultiGeometry>
<Polygon>1
</Polygon>
<Polygon>2
</Polygon>
<Polygon>3
</Polygon>
<Polygon>4
</Polygon>
<Polygon>5
</Polygon>
```

**Attempted Code**

```
sed -i '/<\/Polygon>/a</\MultiGeometry>' text_file
```

This code inserts `</MultiGeometry>` after each match of `</Polygon>` *instead of* the last match of `</Polygon>` in the text file.

**Current Result**

```
<MultiGeometry>
<Polygon>1
</Polygon>
</MultiGeometry>
<Polygon>2
</Polygon>
</MultiGeometry>
<Polygon>3
</Polygon>
</MultiGeometry>
<Polygon>4
</Polygon>
</MultiGeometry>
<Polygon>5
</Polygon>
</MultiGeometry>
```

**Expected Result**

```
<MultiGeometry>
<Polygon>1
</Polygon>
<Polygon>2
</Polygon>
<Polygon>3
</Polygon>
<Polygon>4
</Polygon>
<Polygon>5
</Polygon>
</MultiGeometry>
```

Comment: If your input file contains lines before and after the text already shown then please [edit] your question to show the block of text you're interested in **in context**. Otherwise, with the sample input provided so far, all you need is `echo '</MultiGeometry>' >> file`.

Answer (score 1):

A Perl solution:

```
tac text_file | perl -lpe 'next LINE if $seen; s{</Polygon>}{$&</MultiGeometry>} and $seen++;' > temp
mv temp text_file
```

`tac` : print lines in reverse order, from last to first.

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

`$&` : matched pattern, here `</Polygon>`.
`$seen` : `undef` (false) if we have not replaced yet, and `1` (true) if we have. Enables doing 1 and only 1 replacement of the pattern, the first one from the end = the last one in the original file.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` but indicating `$` (last line in file or in LHS result) as an address

```
sed -irn '/<[/]Polygon>/ { $ s@</Polygon>@&</MultiGeometry>@ }' list1.txt
```

`sed` expression parts

`/<[/]Polygon>/` get all lines matching pattern
`{ $ s@</Polygon>@&</MultiGeometry>@ }` make the replacement only on last line of matched ones. `$` means last line, `&` refers to the whole LHS pattern.

Note: `@` is used instead of `/` in `s/ / /` sed expression for better readability since forward slashes do not require escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Using `gnu-sed` you can use `-z` flag and match `.*</Polygon>` to make sure to match last `</Polygon>` because `.*` is greedy to match longest match before matching `</Polygon>`.

```bash
sed -z 's~.*</Polygon>~&\n</MultiGeometry>~' file

<MultiGeometry>
<Polygon>1
</Polygon>
<Polygon>2
</Polygon>
<Polygon>3
</Polygon>
<Polygon>4
</Polygon>
<Polygon>5
</Polygon>
</MultiGeometry>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing this, with `tac` + `awk` + `tac` combination.

```
tac Input_file |
awk -v RS="" '{sub(/<\/Polygon>/,"</MultiGeometry>\n&")} 1' | 
tac
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, using `tac` on Input_file first to print lines of file into reverse order(from bottom to first line) and passing its output as an input to `awk` program. In `awk` program setting `RS`(record separator) as NULL and in its main program using `sub` to substitute `</Polygon>` with `</MultiGeometry>` and itself(using `&`), then using `1` is an `awk`sh way to print current line. Further sending `awk` code's output as an input to `tac` command to get actual order of lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a relatively flexible solution that can account for more than just polygons :

**CODE**

`{m,g}awk -v __='`***`Octinions`***`' '`

```
BEGIN {
    OFS = FS = (__) ">"
          sub(".$","[&]",FS)
     RS = "^$"
    ORS = ""
} END {
    if (NF == !_) {
        print "none found"
        exit
    }
    if (($!_) ~ "[^<]$") {
        match($!_, "[^<>\n]*$")
        ___ = "</" substr($!_, RSTART) (OFS)

    } else {
        match($!_, "[^\n<>]+[>][\n][<]?[/]?$")
        ___ = "</" substr($!_, RSTART)

        sub("[\n][^\n]*$","",___)
    }
    sub("[\n]","&"___"&",$NF)
    print
}'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<Category_Fields>
<Fields>1
</Fields>
<Fields>2
</Fields>
<Fields>3
</Fields>
<Fields>4
</Fields>
<Fields>5
</Fields>

<Category_Transcendatals>
<Transcendatals>1
</Transcendatals>
<Transcendatals>2
</Transcendatals>
<Transcendatals>3
</Transcendatals>
<Transcendatals>4
</Transcendatals>
<Transcendatals>5
</Transcendatals>

<Category_Distributions>
<Distributions>1
</Distributions>
<Distributions>2
</Distributions>
<Distributions>3
</Distributions>
<Distributions>4
</Distributions>
<Distributions>5
</Distributions>

<Category_Octinions>
<Octinions>1
</Octinions>
<Octinions>2
</Octinions>
<Octinions>3
</Octinions>
<Octinions>4
</Octinions>
<Octinions>5
</Octinions>
```

**`</Category_Octinions>`**

```
<Category_EuclidianPlane>
<EuclidianPlane>1
</EuclidianPlane>
<EuclidianPlane>2
</EuclidianPlane>
<EuclidianPlane>3
</EuclidianPlane>
<EuclidianPlane>4
</EuclidianPlane>
<EuclidianPlane>5
</EuclidianPlane>

<Category_ComplexPlane>
<ComplexPlane>1
</ComplexPlane>
<ComplexPlane>2
</ComplexPlane>
<ComplexPlane>3
</ComplexPlane>
<ComplexPlane>4
</ComplexPlane>
<ComplexPlane>5
</ComplexPlane>

<Category_PartialDiff>
<PartialDiff>1
</PartialDiff>
<PartialDiff>2
</PartialDiff>
<PartialDiff>3
</PartialDiff>
<PartialDiff>4
</PartialDiff>
<PartialDiff>5
</PartialDiff>

<MultiGeometry>
<Polygon>1
</Polygon>
<Polygon>2
</Polygon>
<Polygon>3
</Polygon>
<Polygon>4
</Polygon>
<Polygon>5
</Polygon>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed 'H;1h;$!d;x;s/.*<\/Polygon>/&\n<\/MultiGeometry>/' file
```

Slurp the file into the hold space and using greed, append the required string after the last occurrence of `</Polygon>`.

Alternative, more memory efficient (probably slower):

```
sed '/<\/Polygon>/bb
     x;/./!{x;p;d};x;H
     :a;$!d;x;s/.*<\/Polygon>/&\n<\/MultiGeometry>/p;d
     :b;x;/./p;x;h;ba' file
```

Before the first occurrence of `</Polygon>`, print lines as normal.

Thereafter, keep a copy of lines following `</Polygon>` and only print their contents when the current line is `</Polygon>`.

At the end of the file, search the hold space for the line containing `</Polygon>` and append the required string.

Answer (score 0):

With vim ex mode

```
# to stdout
$ printf '%s\n' '0?</Polygon>?a' '</MultiGeometry>' . %p | ex input_file
<MultiGeometry>
<Polygon>1
</Polygon>
<Polygon>2
</Polygon>
<Polygon>3
</Polygon>
<Polygon>4
</Polygon>
<Polygon>5
</Polygon>
</MultiGeometry>

# inplace
$ printf '%s\n' '0?</Polygon>?a' '</MultiGeometry>' . x | ex input_file

$ cat input_file
<MultiGeometry>
<Polygon>1
</Polygon>
<Polygon>2
</Polygon>
<Polygon>3
</Polygon>
<Polygon>4
</Polygon>
<Polygon>5
</Polygon>
</MultiGeometry>
```